# Implantation of counter in react has a value of 0 when I reference in an empty useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I took code based off [this page](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/build-a-react-timer-component-using-hooks) and adjusted it. I want to time the amount of milliseconds the user is on the component so I want to log the counter value when the component unmounts aka the return statement of useffect/componentWillUnmount().

```
    const [milliseconds, setMilliseconds] = useState(0);
    const isActive = useState(true);

    const logger = new logger(stuff);
  

    useEffect(() => {
        initializeIcons(undefined, { disableWarnings: true });
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            console.log("empty useffect milliseconds:", milliseconds);            
            logger(milliseconds);
            clearInterval(milliseconds)
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        let interval: NodeJS.Timeout =  setInterval(() => {
        }, 0);

        
        interval = setInterval(() => {
            setMilliseconds(milliseconds => milliseconds + 1000);
        }, 1000);
        console.log("interval:", interval);
        console.log("interval milliseconds:", milliseconds);
       
    }, [ milliseconds]);
```

I see the millisecond printout fine in the "interval milliseconds" console statement but the "empty useffect milliseconds:" always prints out 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remember a mount timestamp and then calculate the difference.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const mountedAt = Date.now();

  return () => {
    const mountedMilliseconds = Date.now() - mountedAt;
    console.log(mountedMilliseconds);
  };
}, []);
```

*Side note 1:* use an empty array as deps if you want to run function on mount only. If you do not pass `[]` deps, your `initializeIcons` effect will run with each re-render. Do it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  initializeIcons(undefined, { disableWarnings: true });
}, []);
```

*Side note 2:* first interval you create creates a memory leak, because it does nothing, and is never cleared.

Another problem you have is `milliseconds` dependency in `useEffect`, which registers new intervals after each `milliseconds` state change.

Comment: what do you mean by "use an empty array as deps"? Deps == dependencies? pass it in to where? I definitely do not want to re-render the initializeIcons.

Comment: `Deps == dependencies` - yes. Updated my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: also, when I added a console line in the return of your code:

`return () => {
            console.log("return milliseconds:", milliseconds);
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        };`

I still see it log 0.

Comment: Yes, because this effect is only evaluated once - registers an interval and never re-evaluates again unless re-render. Put console.log below the effect and you will see it working (see updated example). You can also render milliseconds instead of console logging. `return <div>{milliseconds}</div>` at the end of component body.

Comment: sorry, but I'm still confused. I can see that that rendering actually is updating the **milliseconds**, however it doesn't help with what I'm trying to do - which is to log(via custom logger) the milliseconds the component has been mounted. I tried console logging **milliseconds** in return statement of useEffect([] and [mountedAt]) and they both print 0. Does this mean it's actually 0 or just console logging 0?

Comment: Ah, now I got what you want to achieve. This is very easy to do. Will update the answer in a minute.

Comment: Updated. Super simple without intervals :)

Comment: ah yes, I don't even need a timer! Thanks for the help